# Many to many relationships with AngularFire

Tags: rxjs, angularfire

I have a conceptual problem.

I've defined  Many to Many relationship in Firestore. I have 3 collections, A, B and A_B. The A_B collection has documents with IdA_IdB {idA: idA, idB:idB}

What I need is to create and Observable of the documents of B that are related with a
document of A.

I do not know which rxjs operator I need to use or how to. I have tried with switchMap or forEach and MergeMap with no success.

My idea is firstly query the collection A_B using ref.where and pass (idA). Then forEach result query B collection passsing docRef.idB and combine the results in one Observable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, for a specific document A, `docA` you want to:

- query `A_B` collection where `IdA` = `docA.Id` (let's call results "relation")
- for each relation, query `DocumentB` collection where `Id` = `relation.IdB`
- return `docA` with a `relatedBs` property (`DocumentB[]`)

To accomplish this with rxjs, you can use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap), [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) and [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map).

The AngularFire syntax isn't fresh in my mind, but something like this pseudo-code should work:

```js
1  public documentA$ = this.afStore.document(id).pipe(
2    switchMap(docA => this.afStore.collection('A_B').where('idA', '=', docA.id).pipe(
3      switchMap(relations => combineLatest(relations.map(r => this.afStore.document(r.idB)),
4      map(relatedBs => ({...docA, relatedBs}))
     ))
   );
```

Here's an explanation of the flow:

1. fetch the `DocumentA`
2. `switchMap` #1 fetches related `A_B` records
3. `switchMap` #2 fetches the collection of related `DocumentB` documents by using `combineLatest` to create an observable that emits the collection by mapping each relation to an observable that fetches the corresponding `DocumentB`
4. `map` simply returns the original `DocumentA` with a `relatedBs` property appended